# Use of Generics is a subclass

Tags: java, generics

I have this class [1] that I try to use with my class [2]. But, the generics of `MyIdentityMapper` are wrong. I want to create a generic class that when I use it (`MyIdentityMapper`), I passes the correct types. How should I use generics in  `MyIdentityMapper` here?

[1] Mapper class:

```
public class Mapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT> {...}
```

[2] Identity class:

```
public class MyIdentityMapper extends Mapper<K,V,K,V> {
  public void map(K key, V value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    context.write(key, value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your `K` and `V` type parameters on `MyIdentityMapper` so they can be referenced in the rest of the class.

```
public class MyIdentityMapper<K, V> // ... rest doesn't change
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell java what is your generics, something like that

```
class Mapper<K, V, X, M> {

}

class MyIdentityMapper<K,V,X,M> extends Mapper<K,V,X,M> {
    public void map(K key, V value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(k);
        System.out.println(v);
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```